# Como funciona os nodes no javascript?

Tags: javascript

Em muitos posts leio que em javascript manipula elemento dom, também citados como "nodes"

Como é o processo de manipulação desses nodes ?

Qual é a estrutura envolvida? Qual formato? Estilo xml? em tree?

Answer (score 5):

O DOM (*Document Object Model*, ou modelo do objeto "documento") é na verdade uma API à parte, presente nos browsers, mas que não faz parte da linguagem JavaScript em si.

A estrutura é muito simples, é uma árvore, e cada elemento é um nó (*node*) dessa árvore.

Tome o seguinte HTML como exemplo:

```
<body>
    <div>
       <a href="http://example.com">Link</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

A árvore que representa esse DOM seria assim

```
document
  - body
    - elemento <div>
      - elemento <a>
        - texto "Link"
```

Existem vários tipos de nó no DOM: nós de elementos (como `div` e `a`), nós de texto (dentro de algum outro elemento), nós de comentário, nós que representam atributos de elementos, entre outros.

Na API, cada nó do DOM é representado como um objeto, com diversas [propriedades e métodos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). Entre as principais, eu destacaria `firstChild` (primeiro nó filho de um elemento) e `nextSibling` (próximo nó no mesmo nível do elemento), pois apenas com elas é possível atravessar toda a árvore utilizando uma função recursiva estilo *depth-first*:

```js
function traverse(el) {
    if(el.firstChild) traverse(el.firstChild);
    while(el) {
        console.log(el.nodeName, el.nodeType, el.textContent);
        el = el.nextSibling
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
  traverse(document.body);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="http://example.com">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, em debugger para ver como funciona, eu vejo #text, esse #text é um objeto ou ele é em si uma string?

Comment: É um objeto, um *text node*. `#text` é a forma como o console representa esse objeto.